# Converting numpy array with indices to a string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array like this `np.array([0, 3, 2, 1])`
and i have a string `'abcd'`, how do i convert it to `"adcb"`
(the numpy array stores the indices of the abcd-string) currently i use this

```
def string(array, alphabet):
        string = ''
        for x in array:
            string += alphabet[x]
        return string
```

but this is very slow as i have to loop over the entire array, is there a better (and faster) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a numpy solution:

```
array = np.array([0, 3, 2, 1])
alphabet = 'abcd'
s_list = np.array(list(alphabet))
s_list[array]
```

Output:

```
array(['a', 'd', 'c', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

You just need to convert `alphabet` to a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

you can try list comprehension

check below code:

```
s_list = [alphabet[i] for i in array]
return "".join(s_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import numpy as np
ss='abcd'
idx=np.asarray([0,3,2,1])
arr=np.asarray(list(ss))
ss2=arr[idx]
print(ss2)
```